# Can CloudFront handle repeated headers?

Tags: http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762377/cache-control-headers-repeated-valid-or-not-nginx), you can have multiple headers for certain headers, such as `Cache-Control`.

Will CloudFront respect both times that `Cache-Control` appears?  For example, if the Origin were to send it a response with:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Cache-Control: public
```